# Docker Elasticsearch container with volume wrong permissions

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, permissions

I have a problem with my elasticsearch container, when I let docker create elasticsearch volume, it has been created with wrong permissions so I got a problem and the container goes down. Is there a way to add a sh command to my machine to set permissions before start this container or something like that? Or another solution to my problem?

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  db:
    container_name: app_mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: app
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: app
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
    ports:
      - 33066:3306

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: app_elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
      # - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=app
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
```

My log:

```
docker-compose up  
Starting app_elasticsearch ... done
Attaching to app_elasticsearch
app_elasticsearch | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
app_elasticsearch | uncaught exception in thread [main]
app_elasticsearch | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-03-14T02:18:26,157Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "3879d18f5b22", "message": "uncaught exception in thread [main]", 
app_elasticsearch | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes];",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:615) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "... 6 more",
app_elasticsearch | "Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes",
app_elasticsearch | "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]",
app_elasticsearch | "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]",
app_elasticsearch | "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]",
app_elasticsearch | "at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:389) ~[?:?]",
app_elasticsearch | "at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:693) ~[?:?]",
app_elasticsearch | "at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:800) ~[?:?]",
app_elasticsearch | "at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:786) ~[?:?]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:274) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:271) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]",
app_elasticsearch | "... 6 more"] }
app_elasticsearch | ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes];
app_elasticsearch | Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes
app_elasticsearch |     at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
app_elasticsearch |     at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
app_elasticsearch |     at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
app_elasticsearch |     at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:389)
app_elasticsearch |     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:693)
app_elasticsearch |     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:800)
app_elasticsearch |     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:786)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:274)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:211)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:271)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:257)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126)
app_elasticsearch |     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
app_elasticsearch | For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/docker-cluster.log
app_elasticsearch exited with code 1
```

I know that my problem is elasticsearch ownership, because if I comment volume line, it works fine.

I also do not have problem with mysql container...

here is my permissions:

```
ls -la volumes 
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root  4096 mar 13 23:23 .
drwxrwxr-x 13 pedro pedro 4096 mar 13 23:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 mar 13 23:18 elasticsearch
drwxr-xr-x  6   999 root  4096 mar 13 23:23 mysql
```

If I run something like:

```
sudo chown $user:$user volumes/elasticsearch -R
```

Then works, so I believe that docker is creating this dir with root:root instead $user:$user.
Is there a way to fix this without setting manually these permissions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define `user: root` while you build.